# Place to host Strapi with react front end

Tags: reactjs, hosting, strapi

I was asked for create a website for my friends and I've came up with idea that I can use headless cms like Strapi and write frontend with react. Since I'm just a simple code writer I've never need to worry about how my applications are hosted, always someone else do it for me. So here is my problem: I need to create website based on Strapi and react frontend, it is a small page for now and we don't think we are going to have many visitors. Also I'd like to have backend and frontend on same domain. Could you advise me what is the cheapest way to host this? I really can use your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the easiest way then Heroku and Netlify are a good options.

Heroku Strapi tutorial: [Tutorial link](https://strapi.io/blog/deploying-a-strapi-api-on-heroku)

Frontend Netlify: Just link your frontend github repository to Netlify and they will build everything for you. They will also automatically update the page when you push a new commit to the repo. You can also add your api keys to the env variable there to store them safely.

Just make sure to not use SQLite for Strapi as you will lose all your data when your Heroku Dyno restarts.